# Should all "how to do (generic target)" questions be closed?

Tags: discussion

There are lots of questions of persons describing a target and asking how to do it, without any other information. The target is something very generic as "maximize the sales" or "recognize cars". Moreover, usually authors of these questions has none or near than none knowledge on AI and have not done any first try.

Answers can not be specific due to lack of question concretion, usually they contain only the name of the involved AI area. Worst, an usual answer is "yes, use a NN and train it".

Should this kind of question be closed as off-topic ?

Some recent examples:

[How to properly build a neural net of a physics simulation](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/24174/how-to-properly-build-a-neural-net-of-a-physics-simulation)

[Distinguishing Customers from Customer Reps](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/24188/distinguishing-customers-from-customer-reps)

it is easy to find more direct ones.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a question/post? (By the way, I did not downvote this post, and, actually, I think that this question/issue is important). This seems to be related to how much information we are expecting our users to provide in their posts and how much research they should do before posting. I have definitely seen many posts where information was missing or the answer was just one line. In those cases, you should vote to close the post as "needs more details" or flag for deletion (in the case of the one-line answer).

Comment: Thanks for providing an example. I now have a better idea of what you mean. In that specific post, the user seems to know little about machine learning and is trying to get some advice on how to solve his/her problem. It's true that we can't be specific enough, so an answer will need to be general. We have been having indeed many similar questions. This is probably due to the fact that people (outside of ML community) are trying to use ML without really having a solid knowledge of the topic. This type of question definitely does not improve the quality of our site...

Comment: ... but the question is: do we also want to help these people? I think that there are more problematic posts (than that specific one) that members of our community still do not care about. For example, this post: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/24167/2444, which is missing details and can't really be answered properly without making assumptions. This is the type of post that I expect the members of our community, including you, to vote to close as "needs or more details", though nobody did it yet.